# How to centre side by side radio buttons on page

Tags: html, css

I've created side-by-side radio buttons and have tried to center them on my web page but one of the buttons doesn't move when I'm editing the margin sizes. I would like to move the left button more to the left.

My HTML code:

```
<div class="choice"
      <tr>
          <td><input type="radio" name = "dreg">I want to post my event</td>    
          <td><input type="radio" name = "dreg">I want to attend an event</td>
      </tr>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.choice {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px 100px;
  font-size: 150%
}

input[type="radio"]{
  margin: 40px 10px 100px 100px;
  cursor: pointer;

}
```

Comment: use display: inline-block; and add *width* proprieties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.choice {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 150%
}
.choice ul{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.choice ul li{
  margin: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}
input[type="radio"]{
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;

}
```

```html
<div class="choice">
    <ul>
      <li><input type="radio" name = "dreg">I want to post my event</li>
      <li><input type="radio" name = "dreg2">I want to attend an event</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. If this is not what you want, let me know.

```css
.choice {
  display: flex;
  padding: 16px ;
  font-size: 150%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

input[type="radio"]{
  margin: 40px 10px 100px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;

}
```

```html
<div class="choice">
      <tr>
          <div><td><input type="radio" name = "dreg">I want to post my event</td></div>

          <div><td><input type="radio" name = "dreg">I want to attend an event</td></div>

      </tr>
</div>
```